# Get Keycloak group ID from group name (mrparkers/keycloak provider)

Tags: foreach, terraform, keycloak

I am trying to provision Keycloak users via Terraform using the mrparkers/keycloak provider. I am very new to Terraform but have the below which successfully creates a user 'hellfire' and a group 'mrpc-admins'.

vars

```
variable "mrpc-groups" {
    type = map(object({
        name = string
        realm = string
    }))
    default = {
        "10001" = {
            name = "mrpc-admins"
            realm = "mrpc"
        }
    }
}

variable "mrpc-users" {
    type = map(object({
        username = string
        email = string
        first_name = string
        last_name = string
        realm = string
        group = string
    }))
    default = {
        "10001" = {
            username = "hellfire"
            email = "bla@bla.bla"
            first_name = "hell"
            last_name = "fire"
            realm = "mrpc"
            group = "mrpc-admins"
        }
    }
}
```

resources

```
resource "keycloak_realm" "realm" {

  realm = "mrpc"

}

resource "keycloak_group" "group" {
for_each = var.mrpc-groups

realm_id = keycloak_realm.realm.id
name = each.value["name"]
}

resource "keycloak_user" "user" {
for_each = var.mrpc-users

realm_id = each.value["realm"]
username = each.value["username"]
email = each.value["email"]
first_name = each.value["first_name"]
last_name = each.value["last_name"]
}
```

The problem is when trying to use the [keycloak_group_memberships](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mrparkers/keycloak/latest/docs/resources/group_memberships) resource with the below code.

```
resource "keycloak_group_memberships" "group_members" {
  for_each = var.mrpc-users
  realm_id = each.value["realm"]
  group_id = each.value["group"] # this needs to have the group UUID not the name
  members  = [
    each.value["username"]
  ]
}
```

I don't know how to get the Keycloak generated UUID assigned to that group which is what the group_id key requires.

Is there perhaps somehow I can look this up on the fly or something else I can do?

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get individual instance of your `keycloak_group` you can do

```
group_id = keycloak_group.group[each.key].id
```